# Create Msg Read View Outlook

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook

I'm writing an Outlook Addin Ribbon in VB.net and getting on with it rather well, however I've come to a point where I'm stuck.
When sending an item, I also need to save the file in the reading format which it would appear in the 'Sent Items'.

If have tried `mailItem.SaveAs("path", olSaveAsType)` but it only saves as a draft item. Whereby you can edit the text.
I tried to loop through the sent items in the 'sent items' folder after sending, however Outlook hangs whilst my code is executing, thus holding up the actual sending of the email.

Is there a way this can be done?

Any help, hints or tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Message submission is an asynchronous process. Set up the Items.ItemAdd event handler on the Sent Items folder (Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)) and process the sent message in the ItemAdd event handler.